# Python requests "dynamic cookie"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm attempting to send a post request to a website but they have a dynamic cookie. On chrome, when I send a login request, the "cookie" selection in "Request headers"  changes every time. I'm unsure of how I can do use this.

Current code:

```
import requests
headers = {"user-agent":"blah blah","cookie":"blahblah"}
data = {"user":"user","pass":"pass"}
s=requests.Session()
r=s.post(URL, data=data, headers=headers)
```

Usually, I get error codes `400` or `403`